# Google Custom Search using ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i am using ASP.NET MVC2 to implement google custom search. i am able to connect to googleAPI, pass my query, get the results back in JSON format and map those to .NET classes. However, when i create a view to show those results i am receving an error.

```
public ActionResult SiteSearch(string query)
        {
            var googleSiteSearchClient = new GoogleSiteSearchClient();
            var model = googleSiteSearchClient.RunSearch(query);
            return View(model);


        }
```

I create a strongly typed View based on Model and try to use a FOREACH loop to get the results

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>SiteSearch</h2>

   <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>


                <%: item.Kind %> <br />

    <% } %>

    </table>

</asp:Content>
```

i am receving this error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AASD2.Models.GoogleAPI.GoogleSearchResponse', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AASD2.Models.GoogleAPI.GoogleSearchResponse]'.

any suggestion, where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the result of googleSiteSearchClient is not a collection. The search result collection is probably a property on the result of googleSiteSearchClient.

Either use

```
   <% foreach (var item in Model.WhatEverTheCollectionIsNamed) { %>


                <%: item.Kind %> <br />

    <% } %>
```

Or

```
public ActionResult SiteSearch(string query)
        {
            var googleSiteSearchClient = new GoogleSiteSearchClient();
            var model = googleSiteSearchClient.RunSearch(query);
            return View(model.WhatEverTheCollectionIsNamed);        
        }
```

Comment: now, i am getting results back, but the page is showing only first 10 results, any idea where the rest of the results gone? i have updated the post to show the image.